Problem with Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 24.04?
I just upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 and look like the drivers are not working properly with my NVidia G-force 1030x.
Here an example when I open 'settings':

Someone know what could be the reason?
FIXED: I already found the solution, when I had Ubuntu 23, I installed 'nvidia-driver-470' using 'Software & Updates' -> 'Additional drivers'. Now I fixed the problem installing 'nvidia-driver-535'

Default driver (nouveau?) doesn't support your card correctly obviously.

Based on my bad experience with nouveau or default 535 nvidia driver, I tried weeks ago to purge previous nvidia drivers and install the 555 via ppa. You can follow this guide I usually recommend to whoever has problems with ubuntu 24.04 running on nvidia: https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide
